# How to dennote duplicate values based on multiple criteria within a given time period

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have data that looks like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
dat<-data_frame(Date=as.Date(c("2012-08-06","2012-08-06","2016-01-01","2016-12-20","2017-02-01","2015-02-03","2014-12-28","2017-06-06","2017-08-04","2017-10-28")),Person=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),Type=c("A","B","A","A","A","C","C","A","B","C"))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     Date        Person Type
    <date>       <dbl> <chr>
 1 2012-08-06      1     A
 2 2012-08-06      1     B
 3 2016-01-01      2     A
 4 2016-12-20      2     A
 5 2017-02-01      2     A
 6 2015-02-03      3     C
 7 2014-12-28      3     C
 8 2017-06-06      4     A
 9 2017-08-04      4     B
10 2017-10-28      4     C
```

I am attempting to create a binary column that dennotes if a given `Type` is the first instance of the given `Type` for a given `Person` within a one year period (based on `Date`).  Thus, in this case I would obtain the following:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      Date       Person Type   Original
     <date>      <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 2012-08-06      1     A        1
 2 2012-08-06      1     B        1
 3 2016-01-01      2     A        1
 4 2016-12-20      2     A        0
 5 2017-02-01      2     A        1
 6 2015-02-03      3     C        0
 7 2014-12-28      3     C        1
 8 2017-06-06      4     A        1
 9 2017-08-04      4     B        1
10 2017-10-28      4     C        1
```

Comment: Do you want to check it within the Date column or the year of the date ?

Comment: Can you tell us if your original data_frame is large or not ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar It is irrelevant to the question if the data is large. And it is within a year from the `Date` of the `Original` combination of `Person` and `Type`.  Thus, in the case of `Person` 2, we see the first two instances of `Type` A are within the same 365 day period, while the next instance of `Type A` for `Person` 2 is more than 365 days from the original `Date`; thus, it is considered a new original instance.

Comment: i ask the size of the data set to know if it's interesting to do it with loop or with something like data.table to optimize treatment time.

Comment: @OrhanYazar Feel free to make either suggestion, though `data.table` and `dplyr` are always preferrable when possible.

Comment: i have a question about the 5th row of your dataframe. There is an A type with person 1 on 2016-12-20 4th row which is less than one year than the 5th year date 2017-02-01 but you still set Original to 1. Is it normal ? So we have not to take "duplicated" as reference ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar The observation in the 5th row is marked as an original instance because it is more than 365 days after the other original instance of that combination of person and type (i.e., the observation in row 3).  Thus, every subsequent duplicate combination of that person and type will be considered a duplicate for the next 365 days.

Comment: Do you want leap years to be handled or do you really want to use 365 days ?

Comment: Also, with your expected output, a solution that wouldn't reinitiate the cycle start (starting a new cycle at the same date each year) would pass, and as I understand you want to reinitiate the cycle at the new next date after a one year cycle. You could make this clearer by adding a `2018-01-15      2     A` row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution using just dplyr. I got the original date by person and type, left joined it onto the existing data set then just checked to see if the date was within one year of the original and not equal to itself.

Update - I changed the dat3 step to answer the comment below. I put an extra column in for the Reset Date and changed the logic for the datediff variable.

```
    library(dplyr)
    dat<-data_frame(Date=as.Date(c("2012-08-06","2012-08-06","2016-01-01","2016-12-20",
                                   "2017-02-01","2015-02-03","2014-12-28",
                                   "2017-06-06","2017-08-04","2017-10-28")),
                    Person=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
                    Type=c("A","B","A","A","A","C","C","A","B","C"))

    dat2 <- dat %>% 
            arrange(Date, Person) %>%
            group_by(Person, Type) %>% 
            filter(row_number() ==1) %>% 
            mutate(FirstDate = Date) %>% 
            select(-Date)


dat3 <- left_join(dat, dat2, by = c("Person"= "Person", "Type" = "Type")) %>% 
        mutate(Original = ifelse(Date == FirstDate, 1,
                          ifelse(Date - FirstDate <= 365, 0 ,1)),
               datediff = ifelse(Date - FirstDate >= 365, 0, Date - FirstDate),
               ResetDate = as.Date(ifelse(Date - FirstDate > 365 & Original == 1, Date,
                                           FirstDate), origin = '1970-01-01'))
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Any thoughts on how to edit so that `FirstDate` corresponds to the "reset" date?  For example, in the current data row 5 would have `2017-02-01` as the first date and `datediff` would be 0.  I have come up with `dat3$FirstDate<-ifelse(dat3$datediff>365&dat3$Original==1,dat3$Date,dat3$FirstDate)` I can't get it to work right, but regardless it would be preferrable to include as part of the join so no additional coding is required.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the dat3 step for you. Instead of overwriting the FirstDate variable I included a reset date variable to show the FirstDate and when it was reset. You can choose to overwrite the FirstDate if that better suits your needs (although I would not recommend it).

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

I added a process to detect a period reset and i also modified the process which create years indexes to make it detect automatically your year range so you don't have to set it manually.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tis)

#creating our data.table
dat <- data.table(Date=as.Date(c("2012-08-06","2012-08-06","2016-01-01","2016-12-20","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2015-02-03","2014-12-28","2017-06-06","2017-08-04","2017-10-28")),Person=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),Type=c("A","B","A","A","A","A","C","C","A","B","C"))

#creating a year column to merge with year table 
dat$year <- substring(dat$Date,1,4)    

#creationg a year table with a number column which correspond to the number of the year among our list of year
year_table <- data.table(year=as.character(min(dat$year):max(dat$year)),number=1:length(min(dat$year):max(dat$year)))

#merging the two tables
dat <- year_table[dat,on = .(year)]


#seting the number to get exactly to which number correspond the date
dat$number <-  dat$number + yday(dat$Date)/(365 + isLeapYear(as.numeric(dat$year)))

#creating min column by Person and Date which contains the value of min(number)
dat[,min:=ifelse(number==min(number),number,min(number)),by=list(Person,Type)][]


#calculation number - min and comapring it to 0 or 1
dat$diff <- dat$number - dat$min

#if diff==0, it's the first occurence so we set Original to 1, if 0<diff<1 set to 0 and if diff>1 set to 1
dat[,round_diff := trunc(diff)][] #Edit
dat[,temp_Original := ifelse(diff==0,1,ifelse(diff>0&diff<1,0,1)),by=list(Person,Type)][]
dat[,temp_Original2 := ifelse(diff>1 & diff>min(diff),0,1),by=list(round_diff,Type,Person)][] #Edit
dat[,Original := temp_Original*temp_Original2] #Edit

dat[,c("Date","Person","Type","Original")]
```

Comment: This does not provide the correct solution, as it does not consider time.  Again, an observation is considered an `Original` if it is unique by `Person` and `Type` within a one year period from the `Original` instance of that combination of `Person` and `Type`.  Please let me know if additional clarification is needed.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but this still doesn't give me what I need as it only applies to this scenario. Ideally, I wouldn't have to manually specify the years, as they could change, though that is more trivial as I could set the years to large plausible range. The bigger problem is this approach assumes the combo of `Person` and `Type` will not repeat again after the initial 365 day period resets.For example, if `Person 2` were to have `Type` A on the `Date` 2017-03-01 your approach would mark it as an original instance, but it shouldn't be. The new cycle starts on 02-01-2017.

Comment: @costebk08 Can you try with this ? If it doesn't work i can't help you anymore sorry.

Comment: this works thank you for all the effort.  I am posting a bounty to see if a more efficient solution is possible.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative solution with the `data.table`-package:

```
# load the 'data.table' package
library(data.table)

# convert 'dat' to a 'data.table' and set the keys to 'Person' & 'Date'
# (which will reorder the data according to 'Person' & 'Date')
setDT(dat, key = c('Person','Date'))

# create a 'newgroup' variable for each person
# then check for duplicates by 'Person' & 'newgroup'
dat[, newgroup := cumsum(rowSums(abs(outer(Date, Date, '-')) > 365)), by = Person
    ][, original := +(!duplicated(Type)), by = .(Person, newgroup)
      ][, newgroup := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>           Date Person Type original
>  1: 2012-08-06      1    A        1
>  2: 2012-08-06      1    B        1
>  3: 2016-01-01      2    A        1
>  4: 2016-12-20      2    A        0
>  5: 2017-02-01      2    A        1
>  6: 2014-12-28      3    C        1
>  7: 2015-02-03      3    C        0
>  8: 2017-06-06      4    A        1
>  9: 2017-08-04      4    B        1
> 10: 2017-10-28      4    C        1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

We first define a custom function, it takes years in YYYYMMDD format and flags and reinitiates a row when an interval excedes 10000 (so leap years are handled).

We then we use it on the relevant groups.

```
library(dplyr)
new_year <- function(x) {
  is_new <- 1
  if(length(x)>1){
    base <- x[1]
    for (i in 2:length(x)) {
      interval <- x[i] - base
      if (interval >= 10000) {
        is_new <- c(is_new,1)
        base <- x[i]
      } else {
        is_new <- c(is_new,0)
      }
    }
  }
  return (is_new)
}

dat %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(Person,Type) %>%
  do({mutate(., Original=new_year(year(Date)*10000+month(Date)*100+day(Date)))}) %>%
  right_join(dat)

# Joining, by = c("Date", "Person", "Type")
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# # Groups:   Person, Type [?]
# Date Person  Type Original
#        <date>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#  1 2012-08-06      1     A        1
#  2 2012-08-07      1     B        1
#  3 2016-01-01      2     A        1
#  4 2016-12-20      2     A        0
#  5 2017-02-01      2     A        1
#  6 2015-02-03      3     C        0
#  7 2014-12-28      3     C        1
#  8 2017-06-06      4     A        1
#  9 2017-08-04      4     B        1
# 10 2017-10-28      4     C        1
```